# <li> with onlick (switch/checkbox) function

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-lists

I have this rectangle in `<li>` format and wanted it when I clicked on the rectangle that would turn the switch on / off. How is it done with javascript?

[image]

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">
    <i class="icon icon-info"></i>
    Informação Geral
    <label class="labl switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="GeneralInformation" checked="checked" />
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</li>
```

My code:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 26px;
  float: right;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.default:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.primary:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.info:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.warning:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.danger:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.list-group-item {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.card {
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="botoes_selecao">
  <div class="card icon-package-flat">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->

    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

      <li class="list-group-item" onclick=toggleButton(idGeneralInformation)>
        <i class="icon icon-info"></i> Information
        <label class="labl switch">
                                             <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="GeneralInformation" checked="checked" />
                                             <span class="slider round"></span>
                                         </label>
      </li>

      <li class="list-group-item" onclick=toggleButton(idGeneralInformation)>
        <i class="icon icon-info"></i> Information 2
        <label class="labl switch">
                                             <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="GeneralInformation" checked="checked" />
                                             <span class="slider round"></span>
                                         </label>
      </li>



    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Again, what is it you are referring to as a rectangle?

Comment: Add your code with design like (CSS)

Comment: I really can't see the element from the screenshot in the code you posted. Besides  that you ar emissing the actual JS code where you tried to do this, the CSS to show us what snimation to use on right side part (or you are loading this as picture and reload another picture of it when click makign that a terrible design?)

Comment: If you group the icon and such inside the label and style that label, you can use the `for` attribute of the label to trigger the checkbox when it gets clicked. So there's no javascript needed to actually get this effect. A label with the for attribute referring to the checkbox and a checkbox styled as the slider should work.

Comment: start your label at the beginning of the li so it wraps everything (and move any li padding onto it), then you don't need js

Comment: I am assume you are having a different `div` (which you are referring to a rectangle), on click of that `div` you need to toggle the checkbox. Check this fiddle and let me know https://jsfiddle.net/g5L3h7oz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you using switch from w3school. You have one label for decoration `.switch`, now you need an actual label to click on. Wrap content of `li` in label and move the class `list-group-item` from `li` to that label.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 26px;
  float: right;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.default:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.primary:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.info:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.warning:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input.danger:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #00adef;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.list-group-item {
  background-color: #ececec !important;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.card {
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="botoes_selecao">
  <div class="card icon-package-flat">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->

    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

      <li>

        <label class="list-group-item">
      
        <i class="icon icon-info"></i> Information
        <label class="labl switch">
                                             <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="GeneralInformation" checked="checked" />
                                             <span class="slider round"></span>
                                         </label>

        </label>

      </li>

      <li>

        <label class="list-group-item">
      
        <i class="icon icon-info"></i> Information 2
        <label class="labl switch">
                                             <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="GeneralInformation" checked="checked" />
                                             <span class="slider round"></span>
                                         </label>

        </label>

      </li>



    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```